# Difference and similarities between unsupervised region of interest and bag of words model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning

As the title suggests what are similarities and differences between unsupervised learning of  region of interest and bag of words model for computer vision .

Reference-

For unsupervised ROI:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gunhee/publish/nips09_gunhee.pdf

For bag of words model:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/fergus/iccv2005/bagwords.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, these two belong to different fields, bow for image/video classfication and the other one belongs to object detection.

In bow model, region detection is necessary, however, from the link you provided, the region is generated based on the sampled edge points, then we use the descriptor of all regions as a represtation of the image.

however, in 'unsupervised ROI', the goal is to extract the most representative region(which is often an salient object)